# No message found under code txxx' for locale 'en_GB'

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

configuration for Spring MVC for properties file:

In my spring-servlet.xml I have:

```
<bean id="messageSource"
class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
  <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/messages/messages" />
  <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0" />
</bean>
```

Have all the below properties file in the location:

```
messages.properties
messages_en.properties
messages_en_GB.properties
```

I have a global error page set in web.xml:

```
<error-page>
  <error-code>400</error-code>
  <location>/WEB-INF/views/error_404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Except `http://aaa:8080/xx.jsp` all the other bad URLs are getting forwarded to the correct page.

If I use .jsp in my URL I am getting this error:

> No message found under code txxx' for locale 'en_GB'

Answer (score 0):

.jsp in the url is asking for context listener.
so created a context listener and added defined the message resource in the file.
Issue got resolved now.

Why ".jsp" requires context listener while any other format like .html .jsf etc etc are correctly getting pointed to error page